# weird behavious of id command on centos

Tags: centos

how to check in reliable way that a user exists on a system? 
right now the only way is grep of /etc/passwd, becasue `id` command is not reliable, example below (commands sequence is kept below).

```
$ id 100000
id: 100000: no such user
$ sudo adduser -u 100000 testusr
$ id 100000
uid=100000(testu) gid=5663(testusr) groups=5663(testusr)
$ sudo adduser 100000
$ id 100000
uid=5663(100000) gid=5664(100000) groups=5664(100000)
```

Comment: IMO, it's poor management of the system if you're having numerical-only usernames based on this. what's wrong with grepping /etc/passwd or /etc/shadow? `fgrep "<username>:" /etc/passwd` works fine

Comment: Related SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949667/what-are-the-real-rules-for-linux-usernames-on-centos-6-and-rhel-6

Comment: @RoboJohnny, I rather thought that id command does it wrong, is cheated so easily.

Comment: Fair enough. I believe newer versions of rhel-based distros don't let you use numeric-only usernames, likely for this reason (my fedora box abnd a rhel 7 box doesn't anyway..) a workaround still using `id` would be `sudo -u <username> id`

Comment: `grep /etc/passwd ‹username›` fails if you use remote databases (like LDAP). `getent passwd ‹username›` should handle that correctly.

Comment: on rhel 7.4 it is allowed to create digits only usernames, all this comes from external customers - if they use such in their companies why should we deny it?